# How can I find the length of a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to get the length of a number in JavaScript or jQuery?

I've tried `value.length` without any success, do I need to convert this to a string first?

Comment: Yes, convert it to a string. The concept of a number's "length" is only meaningful in terms of some number representation scheme.

Comment: Yes, you need to convert to the string first, 
I.E 
(1234).toString().length

Comment: Benchmarks for top 3 answers: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/92276

Comment: Do not convert into a string because it will fail in case of long numbers. I explicate the complete motivation into my answer.

Answer (score 430, accepted):

```
var x = 1234567;

x.toString().length;
```

This process will also work for`Float Number` and for `Exponential number` also.

Comment: +1'd. In case it's not obvious to anyone, the decimal point in floats will be counted in the string length. e.g. 2.5.toString().length outputs 3.

Comment: @dading84: i guess Math.floor() would fix that:
 Math.floor(99.5454).toString().length === 2

Comment: This solution would not work with large number or small number that has more than 20 digits. eg. 1.2e+22 toString().length outputs 7

Comment: Also to note this is extremely slow.
I did a test in node and it turns out it's more than 1200% slower than Arturs answer.

Comment: It is not good solution, example:
const val = 0295;
const x = val.toString().length;
console.log(x) // output is: 3

Comment: number 01 will be of length 1 when `toString()` is used

Comment: This will also fail even in case of very long numbers because of the exponential notation

Comment: This (accepted) answer is wrong as it assumes base 10.

Comment: We should consider negative numbers too. -1234.toString().length will be 4.

Answer (score 131):

Ok, so many answers, but this is a pure math one, just for the fun or for remembering that Math is Important:

```
var len = Math.ceil(Math.log(num + 1) / Math.LN10);
```

This actually gives the "length" of the number even if it's in exponential form. `num` is supposed to be a non negative integer here: if it's negative, take its absolute value and adjust the sign afterwards.

### Update for ES2015

Now that [`Math.log10` is a thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10), you can simply write

```
const len = Math.ceil(Math.log10(num + 1));
```

Comment: i think this pure math one is most efficient/fastest.

Comment: Awesme perf man thanks. The results i got show the math way is fastet, is this the result you got? here is my result: http://i.imgur.com/9BKxyd3.png

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Oh that's nice. I see that method is basically a math one anyway, but with some speed hacks. It drops a `Math.ceil` and uses a faster `Math.abs` instead. But I honestly didn't expect that performance gain in Chrome... Nice to know!

Comment: Perfect, but gives 0 if thee number is 0 instead 1

Comment: At 1e+16 or more it gives 1 less, so 10000000000000000 returns 16 instead of 17 and so on...

Comment: @GotyMetal This solution has several limitations indeed. First of all, as mentioned in the answer, it doesn't deal with rational numbers. Representation limitations are another issue. It's meant to be more like a theoretical answer rather than a practical one, just to remind that a math trick can sometimes solve your problems in an unusual (but maybe better) way.

Comment: Does not return count after dot, for example 1111.01, return 4 instead of 6

Comment: @Vlad as I said, "`num` is supposed to be a non negative integer".

Comment: @StateLess You could achieve that with `const len = Math.ceil(Math.log10(num + 1)) || 1;`

Comment: @jv-dev Yes, as I've said in the answer: `num` is supposed to be a non negative integer here: if it's negative, take its absolute value and adjust the sign afterwards.

Comment: Maybe this exists a problem? 
```Math.ceil(Math.log10(1 + 1)); //1 ``` is OK, but  ```Math.ceil(Math.log10(0 + 1)); //0 ``` is not right, 0 length should be 1.

Comment: @xgqfrms Yes, there is. It's been mentioned before in the comments. And my reply from 2017-02-23 is still valid.

Comment: Based on an answer on the Math stack exchange, assuming we only care about integers, shouldn't this be
`const len = Math.floor( Math.log10(num) +1 );`? 
My spacing for clarity, not appeasing a linter.


 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-lfloor-log-10-n-rfloor-1

Comment: @James Almost equivalent, the only difference is that wouldn't work for `0`.

Comment: @MaxArt Ah right, good catch, thanks! Edge cases strike again.

Answer (score 25):

Could also use a template string:

```
const num = 123456
`${num}`.length // 6
```

Comment: this is the only answer that works for me because I count a number that begins with 0.

Answer (score 14):

You have to make the number to string in order to take length

```
var num = 123;

alert((num + "").length);
```

or

```
alert(num.toString().length);
```

Comment: This will fail in case of long numbers because of the exp. notation

Answer (score 13):

I've been using this functionality in node.js, this is my fastest implementation so far:

```
var nLength = function(n) { 
    return (Math.log(Math.abs(n)+1) * 0.43429448190325176 | 0) + 1; 
}
```

It should handle positive and negative integers (also in exponential form) and should return the length of integer part in floats.

The following reference should provide some insight into the method:
[Weisstein, Eric W. "Number Length." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NumberLength.html)

I believe that some bitwise operation can replace the Math.abs, but jsperf shows that Math.abs works just fine in the majority of js engines.

**Update**: As noted in the comments, this solution has some **issues** :(

**Update2 (workaround)** : I believe that at some point precision issues kick in and the `Math.log(...)*0.434...` just behaves unexpectedly. However, if Internet Explorer or Mobile devices are not your cup of tea, you can replace this operation with the `Math.log10` function. In Node.js I wrote a quick basic test with the function `nLength = (n) => 1 + Math.log10(Math.abs(n) + 1) | 0;` and with `Math.log10` it worked as expected. Please note that `Math.log10` is not universally supported.

Comment: As curiosity i've performed a JsPerf with nLength method vs toString().length on this....http://jsperf.com/convert-number-to-string-and-get-length/2

Comment: Haha, that's basically the solution I provided! I had no idea it could perform so well.

Comment: I'm sorry, did I say something about me *inventing* the solution or something like that? Why don't you read carefully before posting? For the matter, the algorhythm was discovered way before Steven Wolfram was even born, and anyway the page you linked does *not* provide a solution in Javascript. *I* did, 9 months before you.

Comment: The "+1" should be probably outside of the Math.abs call: Math.log(Math.abs(n) + 1)...

Comment: @hubert-grzeskowiak you are absolutely right, otherwise nLength(10) != nLength(-10).

Comment: At 1e+16 or more it gives 1 less, so 10000000000000000 returns 16 instead of 17 and so on...

Comment: @GotyMetal To be honest I just run the code and for me it starts to misbehave at 1e+14:

> nLength(1e+14)
15
> nLength(1e+15)
15

Comment: @GotyMetal I have included some updates to workaround the issue that you have reported.

Answer (score 9):

There are three way to do it.

```
var num = 123;
alert(num.toString().length);
```

better performance one (best performance in ie11)

```
var num = 123;
alert((num + '').length);
```

Math (best performance in Chrome, firefox but slowest in ie11)

```
var num = 123
alert(Math.floor( Math.log(num) / Math.LN10 ) + 1)
```

there is a jspref here
http://jsperf.com/fastest-way-to-get-the-first-in-a-number/2

Answer (score 9):

You should go for the simplest one (stringLength), readability always beats speed. But if you care about speed here are some below.

Three different methods all with varying speed.

```
// 34ms
let weissteinLength = function(n) { 
    return (Math.log(Math.abs(n)+1) * 0.43429448190325176 | 0) + 1;
}

// 350ms
let stringLength = function(n) {
    return n.toString().length;
}

// 58ms
let mathLength = function(n) {
    return Math.ceil(Math.log(n + 1) / Math.LN10);
}

// Simple tests below if you care about performance.

let iterations = 1000000;
let maxSize = 10000;

// ------ Weisstein length.

console.log("Starting weissteinLength length.");
let startTime = Date.now();

for (let index = 0; index < iterations; index++) {
    weissteinLength(Math.random() * maxSize);
}

console.log("Ended weissteinLength length. Took : " + (Date.now() - startTime ) + "ms");


// ------- String length slowest.

console.log("Starting string length.");
startTime = Date.now();

for (let index = 0; index < iterations; index++) {
    stringLength(Math.random() * maxSize);
}

console.log("Ended string length. Took : " + (Date.now() - startTime ) + "ms");


// ------- Math length.

console.log("Starting math length.");
startTime = Date.now();

for (let index = 0; index < iterations; index++) {
    mathLength(Math.random() * maxSize);
}
```

Comment: may I know why  do you multiply it with `0.43429448190325176`? or do you have any references?

Comment: @Saengdaet the reference is in the name of the function 

Comment: @Jems `1/Math.LN10 === 0.43429448190325176`. See my answer (or others here) for reference.

Answer (score 6):

First convert it to a string:

```
var mynumber = 123;
alert((""+mynumber).length);
```

Adding an empty string to it will implicitly cause `mynumber` to turn into a string.

Comment: Doesn't work with exponentials such as 1e+16 which returns 5.

Answer (score 6):

I got asked a similar question in a test.

> Find a number's length without converting to string

```
const numbers = [1, 10, 100, 12, 123, -1, -10, -100, -12, -123, 0, -0]

const numberLength = number => {

  let length = 0
  let n = Math.abs(number)

  do {
    n /=  10
    length++
  } while (n >= 1)

  return length
}

console.log(numbers.map(numberLength)) // [ 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1 ]
```

Negative numbers were added to complicate it a little more, hence the Math.abs().

Answer (score 6):

```
var x = 1234567;
String(x).length;
```

It is shorter than with `.toString()` (which in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 5):

Well without converting the integer to a string you could make a funky loop:

```
var number = 20000;
var length = 0;
for(i = number; i > 1; ++i){
     ++length;
     i = Math.floor(i/10);
}

alert(length);​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/G8tQE/

Comment: @Pointy yes, this is **assuming** an integer. Even if you make it a string, it will include the `.` as part of the calculation.

Comment: yes, though it's an interesting philosophical question whether the dot should be included in the "length" :-)

Answer (score 3):

A way for integers or for length of the integer part without banal converting to `string`:

```js
var num = 9999999999; // your number
if (num < 0) num = -num; // this string for negative numbers
var length = 1;
while (num >= 10) {
   num /= 10;
   length++;
}
alert(length);
```

Comment: I recommend to add `if (num<0) num = -num;` or `if (num<0) throw Error("Can't handle negative numbers.")` before turning this in a function

Comment: @NiklasE. Ok, added.

Answer (score 3):

I'm perplex about converting into a string the given number because such an algorithm won't be robust and will be prone to errors: it will show all its limitations especially in case it has to evaluate very long numbers. In fact before converting the long number into a string it will "collapse" into its **exponential notation** equivalent (example: 1.2345e4). This notation will be converted into a string and this resulting string will be evaluated for returning its length. All of this will give a wrong result. So I suggest not to use that approach.

Have a look at the following code and run the code snippet to compare the different behaviors:

```js
let num = 116234567891011121415113441236542134465236441625344625344625623456723423523429798771121411511034412365421344652364416253446253446254461253446221314623879235441623683749283441136232514654296853446323214617456789101112141511344122354416236837492834411362325146542968534463232146172368374928344113623251465429685;
let lenFromMath;
let lenFromString;

// The suggested way:
lenFromMath = Math.ceil(Math.log10(num + 1)); // this works in fact returns 309

// The discouraged way:
lenFromString = String(num).split("").length; // this doesn't work in fact returns 23

/*It is also possible to modify the prototype of the primitive "Number" (but some programmer might suggest this is not a good practice). But this is will also work:*/



Number.prototype.lenght = () => {return Math.ceil(Math.log10(num + 1));}

lenFromPrototype = num.lenght();

console.log({lenFromMath, lenFromPrototype, lenFromString});
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I was literally going to say the same thing. This deserves more attention.

Comment: Please don't modify the prototype of built-in language features!  This is a discouraged practice because it results in unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to correct the @Neal answer which was pretty good for integers, but the number 1 would return a length of 0 in the previous case.

```
function Longueur(numberlen)
{
    var length = 0, i; //define `i` with `var` as not to clutter the global scope
    numberlen = parseInt(numberlen);
    for(i = numberlen; i >= 1; i)
    {
        ++length;
        i = Math.floor(i/10);
    }
    return length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of relevant digits (if the leading decimal part is `0` then the whole part has a length of `0`) of any number separated by whole part and decimal part I use:

```js
function getNumberLength(x) {
  let numberText = x.toString();
  let exp = 0;
  if (numberText.includes('e')) {
    const [coefficient, base] = numberText.split('e');
    exp = parseInt(base, 10);
    numberText = coefficient;
  }
  const [whole, decimal] = numberText.split('.');
  const wholeLength = whole === '0' ? 0 : whole.length;
  const decimalLength = decimal ? decimal.length : 0;
  return {
    whole: wholeLength > -exp ? wholeLength + exp : 0,
    decimal: decimalLength > exp ? decimalLength - exp : 0,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#element").text().length;
```

[Example of it in use](http://jsfiddle.net/USpYk/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to convert to string in order to find the length.For example

```
var x=100;// type of x is number
var x=100+"";// now the type of x is string
document.write(x.length);//which would output 3.
```