# checking an int inputs length

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am attempting to hide a group when the number of integers in a field is 4.

```
$("#ssnInput").keyup(function() {
  if ($('#ssnInput').value.toString().length = 4) {
    $('#ssnInputGroup').style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Any idea why this wouldn't work?

Comment: First, don't use `.keyup()` for this, use `.on("input", function () {...` instead. Second, I believe you meant to use `.val()` instead of `.value`. Third, it's better to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952615/how-can-i-find-the-length-of-a-number

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using `jquery` and so you should be doing `.val()` instead of `.value`.

In fact, I think you are mixing up the two things. Even where you are setting the display to none. It should just be `.hide()`.

Finally, for checking the equality of two values to produce a boolean output, use `==` instead of `=` which is actually an assignment operator.

Final Code:

```
$("#ssnInput").keyup(function() {
  if ($("#ssnInput").val().toString().length == 4) {
    $('#ssnInputGroup').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic problem

```
$('#ssnInput').value.toString().length = 4
```

Shoudld be

```
$('#ssnInput').value.toString().length == 4 // or ===
```

Comment: `$('#ssnInput').val().length` will suffice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Number($('#ssnInput').val())=== 4 ) {
 $('#ssnInputGroup').hide();
}
```

You can try this way.