# I want my value modified to always have three decimal digits

Tags: javascript, decimal, rounding, decimal-point

My logic calculates and returns a value based on user input, I want to modify that value to always have three decimal digits

**For example;**

`1` to `1.000`
`1.02` to `1.020`
`2.000004` to `2.000`
`2.5687` to `2.569`

How would I achieve it on javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Number().toFixed()` to do it

```js
const formatVal = (val,precise = 3) =>{
  return Number(val).toFixed(precise)
}

console.log(formatVal(1,3))
console.log(formatVal(1.02,3))
console.log(formatVal(2.000004,3))
console.log(formatVal(2.5687))
console.log("-----------------")
console.log(formatVal(2.5687,2))
```

Comment: My problem is solved, but then I got a new problem out of curiosity, How do I round of to three decimal places only when necessary? For example It is not necessary to round off 1 or 1.09 but only round off numbers like 1.796538 or 44.3374547

Comment: @supremeincubator you need to convert it into a string and check the length after `.`,more details can be found at [how-can-i-find-the-length-of-a-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952615/how-can-i-find-the-length-of-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```js
let newNum  = Number(1.34).toFixed(3);
console.log(newNum);
```